# Simple jQuery Click Not Working, though console log recognizes the function

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

Loading a jQuery dialogue in a plugin.

1. Enqueue at Admin Enqueue Scripts

   ```
   function enqueue_settings_scripts_styles($page) {
       wp_enqueue_script (  'my-plugin', 'path/to/the.js', array( 'jquery-ui-dialog' ));
   }
   add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', enqueue_settings_scripts_styles');
   ```
2. The HTML

   ```
   <a style="cursor:pointer" class="cool-button">Click Me</a>
   ```
3. Script (`the.js`)

   ```
   (function($) {
     console.log( "ready!" ); // this happens
     var detailsButton = $('a.cool-button');
     console.log(detailsButton.click);
     // this prints out to console:
     // function (a,c){return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b)}


     detailsButton.click(function(e) {
       alert('i happened'); // never happens
       e.preventDefault();
     });
   })(jQuery);
   ```

I have spent over an hour trying to troubleshoot this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When enqueuing a script, you should state your script's dependencies. In your case, it's jQuery.

Enqueue your script in the following way:

```
wp_enqueue_script (  'my-plugin', 'path/to/the.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

You may also want to ensure that your script IS loaded in the footer, by setting the last argument to true:

```
wp_enqueue_script (  'my-plugin', 'path/to/the.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true);
```

Where `null` would be the version number and `true` states that the script needs to be loaded in the footer.

Comment: I wish that was the answer. I am actually using `jquery-ui-dialogue` which also pulls in the other two dependencies (`jquery` and `jquery-ui`). I had just left them out for brevity as click itself itn't working. Also you can see that jQuery is enqueued because it prints out it's click function to the console, right?

Comment: This was bugging me too a few days back, until I realized I needed to set the jQuery as a dependency. By the way seeing jQuery being enqueued is not enough. If it's not the case, I'm afraid this question would be off-topic, since it's a jQuery question rather than WordPress. But if you haven't tried, it's worth trying `array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-dialog' )`.

Comment: I think when I set `jquery-ui-dialog`as a dependency, it also sets `jquery` as a dependency. It's possible this is just a jQuery issue. I'm simply not sure yet, because it is within WP that it's happening.

Comment: `array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-dialog' )` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I think the issue is that I needed to set the final argument to `wp_enqueue_script` so that it enqueues in the footer.